# C++ Array of callbacks

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have some troubles creating a vector of callbacks in c++.
I have an interface with one function and 2 classes which implements that interface. I want to call this function from a vector in other part of my program.

I need just that function, so I don't want to store pointers to whole object

Here is a simple example of what I want to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class IAnimal{

public:
    IAnimal(){};
   ~IAnimal(){};
    virtual void eat(int,int) = 0;
};

class Dog: public IAnimal{

    public:
       Dog(){};
      ~Dog(){};

       virtual void eat(int food, int water){
            std::cout<<"Dog: " << food<< " " << water << std::endl;
       }
};

class Cat :public IAnimal{
   public:
       Cat(){};
      ~Cat(){};

      virtual void eat(int food, int water){
            std::cout << "Cat: " << food << " " << water << std::endl;
       }
  };

  class Test{

     private:
         std::vector<void (IAnimal::*)(int, int)> vec;
     public:
        void Init(){
          IAnimal* dog1 = new Dog();
          IAnimal* dog2 = new Dog();
          IAnimal* cat3 = new Cat();

          //here I want to add callbacks to vec
          void(IAnimal::*f)(int, int) = &IAnimal::eat;
          (*f)->dog1.eat;//doesn't work
          vec.push_back(f);


       }

        void RunTest(){

            for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
             {
                //here I call the callbacks
               vec[i](i, i);//also I don't know how this should be called
             }
        }

 };

 void main(){

     Test t;
     t.Init();
     t.RunTest();

     getchar();
 }
```

Comment: what's the question? code: tl;dr: consider using [boost::signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/signals2.html).

Comment: You have pointers to members. You better have an object *somewhere* to invoke them. Methinks saving rather than leaking those allocations in your test initialization may help with that. [See operators `->*` and `.*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access). Or perhaps use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: It's just a simple example of polymorphism

Comment: Use '(dog1->*f)(1, 1);' to call the function. Also, it is not possible, to have a function call (via pointer to member function) without object

Comment: "It's just a simple example of polymorphism" - no, it isn't. A **simple** example of polymorphism would use a simple pointer-to-interface `IAnimal* p` and invoke `p->eat(...)`, thereby firing the appropriate derivation of `eat()` dependent on the object-type `p` was assigned on creation. No pointer-to-member management is needed. This is considerably different. Is this just for your own learning or some academic malaise you've encountered?

Comment: Is there ANY reason you can't just store the pointers to the animals in a vector, and then call each one's `eat` function?

Comment: @WhozCraig I was answering the first comment with code tl;dr :).  It's for an academic project from a much complicated scenerio, but I simplified some things

Comment: @MatsPetersson Not really to be honest. But I was wondering if this could work and also learn some c++ this way :) Performance wise it's the same maybe just for encapsulation

Comment: So "the C++ way" to solve the problem is to have a vector of pointer/reference to the object, and all the `eat` function. Using callbacks in the way that you describe is useful if you have `static` functions, but if the function is `virtual`, the you already have an indirection available (and if the function is NOT `static` you need to supply the object that the function takes as a hidden argument, so you need some object anyway).

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thank you very much now I understand how this works. I will store pointers to the objects in this case

Comment: If you *really* want an array of callbacks married to existing objects, one such way to do it with C++11 or later [is something like this](http://ideone.com/zDfmy5). Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

When you have polymorphism and using virtual functions, you need an object. So your code:

```
    void RunTest(){

        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
         {
            //here I call the callbacks
           vec[i](i, i);//also I don't know how this should be called
         }
    }
```

won't work, since the OBJECT that you are passing to the callback is missing. So although this would potentially call the `eat` function, it has no animal object that is being passed as the hidden argument. As such, this code will NEVER work as written.

It is technically possible to call virtual functions via function pointers, but generally I'd say that's a "bad smell" (sign of bad code, in other words).

My suggestion for the problem described would be to use a `std::vector<IAnimal*> vec;` and then use `vec[i]->eat(i, i);`.

If you have a different actual problem, then I would suggest you restart with a new question is a more realistic variant of the scenario you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks once again for your explanations

Comment: Upticked (too good not to).